# how does this window resize function work?

Tags: javascript

A while back i asked for a javascript function that would allow me to resize content within a browser window at a set interval. Like, not with every pixel-sized change. I was given this function:

```
function throttle (func, wait) {
    var throttling = false;
    return function(){
        if ( !throttling ){
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            throttling = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                throttling = false;
            }, wait);            
        }
    };
}


window.onresize = throttle(function() {
    resize_columns();
}, 20);
```

The person said that at that time s/he did not really have time to explain closures. I still don't understand how it works. Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml

Comment: What closures basically do is that they let the anonymous function (declared with `function() {...}` see the local variables "around" it. I'd expect this to actually be *more* intuitive to people who start with a language  that has them, as opposed to people who know why closures are difficult to implement.

Comment: @millimoose thank you. can you be a bit more specific about "around" it?

Comment: In your sample, it means that the function you pass into `setTimeout()` can read and write the value of `throttling`, which is a local variable of the function `throttle()`. More importantly, for every *invocation* of `throttle()`, the corresponding anonymous function can access a different `throttling` variable - this is the advantage over using a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous function being returned forms a closure over the 'throttling' variable.  So even when your stack unrolls, and the function throttle() goes 'out of scope'.  The anonymous function will STILL have access to the 'throttling' variable.

Closures are awesome.. I use them ever day and they are still like magic for me.. (It's less magical once you understand how they are implemented on the heap but I digress  :)

Comment: still not quite sure i totally get it, but thank you! Can you show me another example of how you use closures daily to perform magic? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok.. don't you think it's magic that the anonymous function that you return has access to 'throttling' variable once it goes out of scope? The throttle() function ceases to exist.. yet the variable that it declared is still accessible..

Comment: oh, no. I think it's very cool. I just wanted another example of how you use it day-to-day. I wasn't being sarcastic in the least.

Comment: I never thought you were being sarcastic and I apologize if it appeared so.  I just stand in awe at closures and get too excited for my own good  :)